# How can I get query string from path

Tags: jquery, html

```html
<script src="//files.mywebsite.com/js/main.js?cdn=%2f%2fcdn.path.com%2fweb"></script>
```

I want to get string after from `cdn`parameters how can I get string, I mean I want to get this section:

```
%2f%2fcdn.path.com%2fweb
```

Comment: I only think a solution is rewrite that URL and re-build script by server script :D

Comment: You do not understand the OP's question

Comment: @Sandman, I think OP want to how do get query of js file in that js file, Is not query of the html file

Comment: yes exactly I want this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `location.search`[0]

In your example, you can get what you want with:

```
location.search.split("=")[1]
```

[0] https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp

L.E.
Now I get it. If you want to select that from jQuery, maybe something like this can work.

```
let value = $('script[src*="//files.mywebsite.com/main.js"]').src.split("=")[1];
console.log(value)
```

Comment: so how wil I apply this with my code I want to give a alert only

Comment: You do not understand the OP's question

Comment: thanks so I want to ask what is the different between var and let ?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will return a JavaScript Object containing the URL parameters:

```
// Read a page's GET URL variables and return them as an associative array.
function getUrlVars()
{
var vars = [], hash;
var hashes=window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
  for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
  {
     hash = hashes[i].split('=');
     vars.push(hash[0]);
     vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
  }
  return vars;
}
```

For example, if you have the URL:

```
http://www.example.com/?me=myValue&name2=SomeOtherValue
```

This code will return:

```
{
  "me"    : "myValue",
  "name2" : "SomeOtherValue"
}
```

[Reference Link](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html)

Comment: You do not understand the OP's question